# ArrayList is not returning the array but the last element

Tags: java, arraylist

All, I'm having what appears to be simple problem not in loading the array but looping through the list after loading.  Seems it always returns the last record loaded regardless.  I've tried to limit what was stored in the ArrayList (itemVal=2) to see if that was the only value returned.  But it's not.  Code below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testNewClass{
// element layout:
// String defTitle
// int seriesVal
// int itemVal
// double x coordinate
// double y coordinate

static String defTitle;
static int seriesVal;
static int itemVal;
static double xCoordinate;
static double yCoordinate;

/*
 * Private constructor
 */
private static ArrayList<testNewClass> testList = new   ArrayList<testNewClass>();

/*
 * Methods
 */
public static void setAll(String title, int series, int item, double x, double y){
    testNewClass newTest = new testNewClass();
    newTest.defTitle = title;
    newTest.seriesVal = series;
    newTest.itemVal = item;
    newTest.xCoordinate = x;
    newTest.yCoordinate = y;    
    if (item == 2){
        testList.add(newTest);
        System.out.println("count of testList="+testList.size());
        System.out.println("LOADING..series="+series+" item="+item+" x="+x+" y="+y);            
    }
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.defTitle = title;
}

public static String returnNext(int Series, int Item){
    String rtnVal = null;
    System.out.println("testList(size)="+testList.size()+"..Series="+Series+"..Item="+Item);
    for (int i=0; i<testList.size(); i++){
        int nSeries = testList.get(i).seriesVal;
        int nItem = testList.get(i).itemVal;
        System.out.println("X="+testList.get(i).xCoordinate);
        System.out.println("(i)="+i+" nSeries="+nSeries+" nItem="+nItem);
        if (nSeries == Series && nItem == Item){
            double lX = testList.get(i).xCoordinate;
            double lY = testList.get(i).yCoordinate;
            rtnVal = "x=" + lX + " y="+lY;
            break;
        }
    }
    return rtnVal;
}
```

}

Comment: This code is hard to read and makes no sense.  Why are you storing a List of instances of a class that has nothing but static members?  Do you realize that "static" means "true for the class"?  Every instance will have the same values.

Comment: It is called from another class to store x & y coordinates along with some other data in an array (list).

Comment: Thanks. Problem resolved.  Static reference on the element values of the class was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is closer to the mark.  Note that the last point is indeed the one it returns, and all the points in the series are independent.

```
package cruft;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * Series encapsulates a List a Points
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 12/20/2015.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34387750/arraylist-is-not-returning-the-array-but-the-last-element
 */
public class Series {

    private List<Point> points;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Series series = new Series();
        double x = 0.0;
        double y = 0.0;
        double dx = 0.1;
        int numPoints = 21;
        double minY = -1.0;
        double maxY = +1.0;
        Random random = (args.length > 0) ? new Random(Long.valueOf(args[0])) : new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; ++i) {
            series.addPoint(new Point(x, y));
            x += dx;
            y = minY + (maxY-minY)*random.nextDouble();
        }
        System.out.println(series);
        System.out.println(series.getLastPoint());
    }

    public Series() {
        this(null);
    }

    public Series(List<Point> points) {
        this.points = (points == null) ? new ArrayList<Point>() : new ArrayList<Point>(points);
    }

    public void addPoint(Point p) {
        if (p != null) {
            this.points.add(p);
        }
    }

    public Point getPoint(int index) {
        return this.points.get(index);
    }

    public Point getLastPoint() {
        return this.getPoint(this.points.size()-1);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Series{" +
                "points=" + points +
                '}';
    }
}

class Point {
    public final double x;
    public final double y;

    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point{" +
                "x=" + String.format("%10.5f", x) +
                ", y=" + String.format("%10.5f", y) +
                '}';
    }
}
```